# Getting Column Names from Query, issue with Single Quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set example I found to get Column names, this is working perfect on simple queries, but when I have a query with single quotes in, it doesn't work.

Would anyone have a suggestion to get around this?

```
SELECT name 
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
('Select [Current Status] = CASE  WHEN Matter.ArchiveStatus = 0 THEN 'Live' WHEN Matter.ArchiveStatus IS NULL THEN 'Live' WHEN Matter.ArchiveStatus = 1 THEN 'Pending Deletion' WHEN Matter.ArchiveStatus = 2 THEN 'Archived' ELSE 'Unknown' END FROM Matter', NULL, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use another single quote in order to escape the original single quote. Like this:

```
('Select [Current Status] = CASE  WHEN Matter.ArchiveStatus = 0 THEN ''Live''...
```

Comment: This is working thank you, but it gives me other issues,

I am building this into an API, So I want to be able to use this Query in more then one place, if I have to use double quotes it would break as a 'normal' query

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand the situation exactly; but, what if you define the statement with placeholders for the strings, then apply the logic for the single values (so, doubling the quotes if they are in them?)

Answer (score 0):

What about to create a stored procedure to utilize this in normal parameterized way?
e.g.:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetResultSetColumnNames]
    @query nvarchar(4000)
as 
begin
    set nocount on;
    SELECT name 
    FROM 
        sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (@query, NULL, 0)
end
```